# Algebraic simultaneous equations problem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

How many sets of integers $ \{x,y,z\} $ satisfy bo

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: one dumb approach -- substitute $z=54-x-y$ into the quadratic equation, simplify and change variables, to eliminate the cross term $xy$ and this should reduce into 2 complete squares

Comment: Bruteforce answer: [(1,26,27),(2,21,31),(5,15,34),(9,10,35)]

Comment: What is "bo" and how does one satisfy it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\underbrace{(x+y+z)^2}_{2916}=\underbrace{x^2+y^2+z^2}_{1406}+2z\underbrace{(x+y)}_{54-z}+2xy$$
 thus
$$z^2-54z+(755-xy)=0$$
as a result
 $$z=27+\sqrt{xy-26}$$
or
 $$z=27-\sqrt{xy-26}$$